# How can I redirect my page to the root of the website from my portlet?

Tags: jquery, portlet

When a user clicks on a "close" link in my portlet, I need to log him out and redirect him to the homepage. It does seem trivial, but here's when it gets tricky: we are using the Portlets API, Struts 2 and jQuery to compose pages.

So from my portlet's context, I can't simply reference the website's root.

I have managed to invalidate the session once I click on close (using an action), how can I redirect the entire page (composed of different portlets) to the homepage?

Comment: differences with portal and portlets when you use a whole web application filtered with struts2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When developing a portlet, you specifically can't do full page redirects through the API - that's the point in the portlet API: As a portlet developer you don't know whom you share the page with, and you're well shielded from the HttpRequest.

The portal might already have started to send the response back - so that it's too late to send a redirection response code. It might have decided to utilize Ajax to deliver your portlet's HTML fragment. This also likely wouldn't result in the expected behaviour.

One (noncooperative) way that I see for this redirect is to generate Javascript code that redirects the page while it's rendered. Why noncooperative? Well: Every single portlet might generate such code, but naturally only the first one wins. Which one is the first? Undefined. If the whole page is rendered in a single document, it might be the first on the page. If the portlets are delivered individually through Ajax: Who knows.

However, if you log out someone (which you probably also do in a nonstandard way, not guaranteed to work), you might just configure the page you're on to be private, e.g. requiring a login. Liferay will then automatically redirect you to a login page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Struts2 you can add an interceptor that checks for a logged in user before each action and redirects to a global result if there is no logged in user.

```
public class LoginInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        if (invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession().get(Const.USER) != null) {
            return invocation.invoke();
        }
        else {
            return "globalLogin";
        }
    }

}
```

Add the interceptor to the interceptor stack in struts.xml

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor name="loginInterceptor" class="business.interceptor.LoginInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
```

Then put this in your struts.xml that redirects to your main action (the one that displays the home page)

```
<global-results>
    <result name="globalLogin" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">main</param>
    </result>
</global-results>
```

Comment: that would be what I'd do, except since pages are a composition of portlets, I don't really have a main action to redirect to... I also tried redirecting to the url directly using type="redirect" and the full url as a location, but that did not work.